# Can CentOS be set to pure EBCDIC?

Tags: character-encoding, ebcdic

I need to directly manipulate files from a mainframe. Text would be encoded in EBCDIC. Data can contain binary and packed decimal fields. I know I can deal with the data. I am trying to avoid the conversion(s). (and the trouble with converting each field based on it being text or binary). I am familiar with mainframe, USS and CentOS systems. What I would like to do is flip CentOS to be pure EBCDIC. A search on the internet and StackExchange has revealed very little.

I saw an article where Sammyrulez had "... succesfuly added EBCDIC support to a CentOS box by adding lang and encoding to /etc/i18n/sysconfig."

It seems like there should be more to it than this.

I plan to use COBOL via GCC or whatever product works best. (one hurdle at a time)

Has anyone been through this already?

Answer (score 2):

No, it would be impossible to make the whole system work in EBCDIC. This would require recompiling all programs and modifying the source code of quite a few of them (a lot of programs make assumptions like “ASCII uppercase letters are exactly the characters between `A` and `Z`”).

You can make specific programs work with EBCDIC. Not a lot of programs support it — it's rather a niche application these days. The program `dd` can convert between ASCII and EBCDIC (at least one flavor of EBCDIC), but it converts its whole input, not selected fields. With mixed data like you have, your best bet is to program carefully, and convert the EBCDIC fields to ASCII and back if you need to interpret them as text.

Answer (score 0):

As Giles said no. But there are tools you may be able to use to work with EBCDIC. You can not use the standard linux/unix tool-set on these files.

Also you could have trouble transferring Mainframe VB files (not all file transfer programs handle Mainframe-VB files).

Many Java programs  (e.g. **JEdit**) can handle EBCDIC (CP037 or IBM037 is US Ebcdic) but most will not handle **Fixed width** or **VB** file structures used on the mainframe.

From memory [GNU-Cobol](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/?source=directory) (+ many other Cobol compilers) have methods of dealing with EBCDIC files. GNU-Cobol also has a Mainframe compatibility mode which will use mainframe binary sizes. Some Cobol vendors (Microfocus ) offer smart Cobol-Cobol conversion programs that will convert a Mainframe Cobol file to there own format. Obviously Redefines are a big problem.

Shameless plug of my own Software: The [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/?source=navbar) can edit / update Mainframe files in Fixed-Width / VB formats using a Cobol Copybook. It also has Cobol-to-Cobol utility that will try and convert simple Mainframe Ebcidic files to an Equivalent Gnu-Cobol ascii file. Again ReDefines are a big problem.